# retuning null value on getActivity() after Firebase updates the database and gets back to the fragment

Tags: android, listview, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase in my project. I have a navigation drawer to navigate through different fragments. everything was working until I added onItemLongClick on my listView. at the bigining, when the app starts, I can go to my listview and add and remove items without problems. But when I go to another fragment, and come back to that listview, the listview is working fine but once I do the onItemLongClick to remove, the Firebase removes the element in the database instantly, but the  getActivity() on onCreate function returns null and crashes the app. I am doing the same mistake in adding method, because I get the same error on adding. Herein is my code:

```
public class dressListActivity extends Fragment {

    ListView dressListView;
    DatabaseReference databaseDresss;
    myDressAdapter dressAdapter;
    Query queryMyDresss;
    ArrayList<DressDataModel> dressList= new ArrayList<DressDataModel>();;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        queryMyDresss = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dresses").orderByChild("dressCreatorId").equalTo(userID);

        queryMyDresss.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                dressList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    DressDataModel dress = postSnapshot.getValue(DressDataModel.class);
                    dressList.add(dress);
                }
                //getActivity() returns null in the below line:
                dressAdapter = new myDressAdapter(getActivity(),dressList);
                dressListView.setAdapter(dressAdapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
dressListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) 

        DressDataModel dress = dressList.get(i);
        deleteDress(dress);
        return true;


    }
});
});
        dressListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        closetListActivity pla=new closetListActivity();
        Bundle args =new Bundle();
        DressDataModel dress = dressList.get(i);
        args.putString("DRESS_ID",dress.getDressId());
        args.putString("DRESS_NAME",dress.getDressName());
        args.putString("DRESS_CREATOR_ID",dress.getDressCreatorId());
        pla.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_dress_main,pla);
        ft.commit();

    }
});
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("Dress List");
    databaseDresss = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dresses");
    dressListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dressListview);
    //-------------------------------------------
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dress_list,container,false);
    dressListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dressListview);

    return  view;
}
private void deleteDress(DressDataModel dress) {
    DatabaseReference eventContactsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dresses");
    eventContactsRef.child(dress.getDressId()).removeValue();
    dressList.remove(dress);
}
}
```

and here is my main activity having navigation code

```
private void navigationSelectedScreen(int i)
{
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (i)
    {
        case R.id.nav_Search:
        fragment = new ActivedressActivity();
        break;
    case R.id.nav_myJukebox:

        fragment = new dressListActivity();
        break;
    case R.id.nav_favorite:
        fragment=new favoriteListActivity();
        break;
    case R.id.nav_message:
    fragment = new MessageActivity();
        break;
    case R.id.nav_friends:
        fragment = new MessageActivity();
        break;
}
if (fragment!=null)
{
    FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_dress_main,fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

Error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.dress.pooya.dressy, PID: 933
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:233)
                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:181)
                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:166)
                      at com.dress.myDressAdapter.<init>(myDressAdapter.java:37)
                      at com.dress.dressListActivity$1.onDataChange(dressListActivity.java:75)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaie.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaje.zzcta(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajh$1.run(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: You would save everyone trying to help you a lot of time if you would edit your post and include the Error message from you logcat.

Comment: Error message added.

Comment: Two things that jump out at me are (1) Most of the event handlers you have in `onStart` should be introduced in `onCreateView` and (2) This bit of code looks a bit odd `dressListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) 

        DressDataModel dress = dressList.get(i);
        deleteDress(dress);
        return true;


    }
});
});`

Comment: Take a look at the Android lifecycle.  The event handlers you have in `onStart` will be repeated even though they were created the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Your post includes this code containing a comment indicating `getActivity()` returns null.

```
    queryMyDresss.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            dressList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                DressDataModel dress = postSnapshot.getValue(DressDataModel.class);
                dressList.add(dress);
            }
            //getActivity() returns null in the below line:
            dressAdapter = new myDressAdapter(getActivity(),dressList);
            dressListView.setAdapter(dressAdapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

In this code, when adding a listener, you should use [addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)), not `addValueEventListener()`, which  leaves the listener attached.  When the user navigates away from `dressListActivity` (which despite the name is actually a fragment), the fragment is detached from the host activity, so `getActivity()` returns null. But the fragment still exists in memory with the active listener, so when the data at the query location changes, `onDataChange()` fires and the NPE occurs.

Comment: Thank you @Bob! 
I got around the problem by 
Activity parentActivity=(Activity) view.getContext();
But once I read your solution, I changed it to what you suggested. Thank you again!